# svnsync changes to the copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created a copy of a repository using the svnsync command, but have now been informed by a developer that he has changes that weren't committed to the source repository.

If I get him to copy check out a copy of the code from the copied repository, copy his changed source files into it, he should then be able to commit those against the copy, is that correct?

Or am I better of getting him to commit his changes on the source, blowing away the copy and re-syncing?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Well, what would take less added up time/effort for you and the developer(s)? Ideally same end result, so...

Comment: The repository is quite large, as far as I know we have no need to keep the original up-to-date.  If the changes were made to the original, can the copy be updated, or does the sync not handle that?

Comment: Upon further reading and experimenting re-running the sync only update the mirrored repository so I was able to get the commits performed to the old and refresh.